# How to join with NULL values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that has a column (CHECK_ID) that contains NULL values. This column has datatype: INT. If these are null values, I return an 'ND' value and I convert this column to STRING.

I also have another table that contains the same column. The datatype for this column is already in STRING and contains 'ND' records.

However, when I join these tables together, it is not returning any of the NULL values that I set 'ND' for.

```
select 
COALESCE(a.CHECK_ID::TEXT, 'ND') as CHECK_ID,
from TABLE_A a
     left join TABLE_B f
     on f.CHECK_ID::text = a.CHECK_ID::text
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to move the `coalesce()` into the join condition. Is that `'ND'` value going to match successfully in the join though?

Comment: Your alias is the same name as the column in the coalesce. When you get to the on condition, it's looking at the column not the alias.

Comment: Actually I re-read @GregPavlik's comment and he's not wrong at all. You can't redefine a column that way. `SELECT` is actually a later "step" in the processing of the query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the COALESCE in the JOIN as well.

```
select 
COALESCE(a.CHECK_ID::TEXT, 'ND') as CHECK_ID,
from TABLE_A a
     left join TABLE_B f
     on f.CHECK_ID::text = COALESCE(a.CHECK_ID::TEXT, 'ND')
```

or a LEFT OUTER JOIN may also do the trick.

```
select 
COALESCE(a.CHECK_ID::TEXT, 'ND') as CHECK_ID,
from TABLE_A a
     left out join TABLE_B f
     on f.CHECK_ID::text = a.CHECK_ID::text
```

In your SQL you're only changing to ND in the select part of the sql (returned data), in the join they're still null (source data).  The INNER JOIN only returns the rows that match in both tables, which is why they're not being returned.
So you can either add COALESCE in the join statement.   Or if all NULL values in TABLE_A need to be ND then a LEFT OUTER JOIN will work, since LEFT OUTER also returns non matching rows from the right side table, and sets all fields to NULL.